# Covariant derivate of tensor itself

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, covariance, euler-lagrange-equation

In the context of Higgs physics when solving the Euler-Lagrange equation I end up with derivatives like the following

$\frac{\partial A^\nu}{\partial A^\mu}$

$\frac{\partial A_\mu}{\partial A^\mu}$

Could someone explain to me how to resolve these?

---  Update -----

Further the following derivate occurs

$\frac{\partial (\partial^\mu A^\nu)}{\partial (\partial^\nu A^\mu)}$

This one is obviously much harder than the previous ones. While I feel like getting the clue for the previous ones, I have a hard time resolving this one. As far as I know the result should be a scalar, looking at the Indices.

---- Update 2 -----

For anyone interested, the answers for the first two can be found below. 
For the derivate introduced in the first update, I decided to change the indices in the Euler Lagrange equation leading to the derivate

$\frac{\partial (\partial^\mu A^\nu)}{\partial (\partial^{\nu^,
} A^{\mu^,})}$

This can then be easily found to be

$\delta_{\nu^,}^\mu \delta_{\mu^,}^\nu$

Comment: Could you expand a little; try to include the EL equations that lead to the above relations?

Comment: I am working with the Lagrangian (8) from here (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/phys/theoretical-physics/itp-dam/documents/gaberdiel/proseminar_fs2018/21_Bertle.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiLoe6_vIzjAhXZShUIHVVNBXgQFjABegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw0dcVdJJ0bQjOi8SPH5oBOZ) and try to perform the $A^\mu$ variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defined to give kronecker deltas.

The first is $\delta_\mu^\nu$ and the second contracts the indices to form the trace of the identity, yielding D, the space time dimension.

Comment: I get the first one. But shouldn't the second one be $g_{\mu \nu} \delta^\nu_\mu$ ?

Comment: If I then lower the Index of the Kronecker Delta I would get $\delta_{\nu \mu}$ and as far as I know I cannot sum there, because to do so one Index must be up and one down.

Comment: * I meant $\delta_{\mu \mu}$ which I don't think is a thing.   On the other hand I could also get $g_{\mu \mu}$, but I have never seen that anywhere else

Comment: Sure but if g is eta you will get the trace of the identity

Comment: I mean your number 2 has no free index so it must be a scalar

Comment: Are you sure about that? Isn't the derivation by a contravariant vector a covariant vector itself i.e. $\frac{\partial A_\mu}{\partial A^\mu} = \partial_\mu A_\mu$ with the shorthand $\frac{\partial}{\partial A^\mu} = \partial_\mu$ ?

Comment: Well as you wrote it it doesn't make sense in th sense of the summation convention, so I assumed you had intended for one of the indices to be raised. If not, and you kill the sum over  mu then the answer is 1

Comment: I see what you mean. But with a metric tensor diagonal of (-1,1,1,1) the derivate should be the mu'th diagonal value of the metric tensor. Thus $g_{\mu \mu}$ with mu as a fixed value, no summation, right?

Comment: Yes, that's fine

Comment: Now you should be able to do your update - they are tensors. Fix the indices to be different first and then put them equal

Comment: Thx, I updated the question

Comment: Your answer is correct! If you're happy with my answer you could mark it as the accepted answer :-)